# java googlemail blocks multiple access

Tags: jakarta-mail

I need to allow a user of my App to email themselves when an even occurs.  I am not sure how to do this.

My first idea is to create a dummy gmail account, and have my App sign-in and send from there via java code. This means hardcoding the password BUT as account not used for anything other than one way emailing - it does not seem to be a problem.

However, I understand that google is pretty proactive about security and if my App (which is global) tries to log into same account in several different countries during a 24 hour period - it will block the email.

I have seen the "delegate" functionality, but that would mean that each user needs their own gmail account which is not practical.

Is there a way to force gmail to allow the sign-ins to happen from wherever?

Or is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Gmail is not designed for bulk sending.  Use an actual bulk email service like SendGrid or Mailgun.

Comment: Also, make sure that spammers can't misuse the account/service.

Comment: It's not bulk email. Just each user may wish to have my App send them an Alert occaisionally

Answer (score 0):

probably not a good idea to have your app to mail from a private account, if I understand you correctly. Best  to use email service like http://expresspigeon.com or http://sendgrid.com and simply send a transactional email from your app account. In other words, use an ESP.

Comment: How does the message get to expresspidgeon.com though?

Comment: If I send a single transaction I still need to hard code the x-ath-key - will expresspidgeon not block this it it sent from multiple user machines?

Comment: it will not be blocked, since you are using the same expresspigeon account. This will be your account, not your users accounts.

Comment: @ManInMoon: That's still a bad idea; spammers can steal your key & use it to send spam.  You should make your own server that accepts requests, makes sure they're legitimate, and actually sends the email.

Comment: @SLaks Is there a simple example of code for a server to do this please

Comment: @SLaks, I have to disagree. Building your email infrastructure is a separate profession and is not for faint-hearted. I agree that the auth key must be protected in your app. There are many ways to do this, every language has means

Comment: @ipolevoy: No; I mean make a server that calls out to an ESP such as SendGrid. You're right that he definitely should not build his own SMTP infrastructure.  However, there is no way to secure a key in a client-side app.

Answer (score 0):

The safest would be to ask the user for all the configuration information necessary to access their email server as themself, then send the email as themself to themself.  You can use JavaMail to send the message, but you'll need to ask for all the configuration information that any other email application would ask for in order to configure access to their mail server.

There may also be Android-specific ways to do this using the default email application.